# $elemMatch works on a normal field inside the array?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

```
"grades": [
     { "date": { "$date": 1393804800000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 2 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1378857600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 6 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1358985600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 10 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1322006400000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 9 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1299715200000 }, "grade": "B", "score": 14 }
  ],
```

Here **grades** is an array denoted by [] but the inner field **score** is not an array since it contains a normal value 2 or 6.

So, why is the following query using $elemMatch over **score**?

> db.restaurants.find({grades : { $elemMatch:{"score":{$gt : 90}}}});

https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb-exercises/mongodb-exercise-8.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

So in this case left handside `grades` is an array you want to query against using `$elemMatch`. The the right handside represents a **query** (`score > 90`) which gets evaluated against every element of `grades` array and if it returns `true` for any element then the document will be returned.

Alternatively, in this case you can use the dot notation syntax:

```
.find( { 'grades.score': { $gte: 90 } } )
```

which may be more intuitive.

Comment: But with this dot notation $elemMatch cannot be used?

Comment: No, it's equivalent in this case but when you want to apply more than one condition for the same element you need to use `$elemMatch`